# write a Java program to show the value of the hundreds place, the tens place, and the ones place for a three-digit number

Tags: java

I am a noob to java and I need advice to fix this code, I need to write a Java program to show the value of the hundreds place, the tens place, and the ones place for a three-digit number. This is what I have so far, any ideas to how to get it to work? I'm not getting any errors, but my number isn't even outputting to the console correctly. Like if I typed in 123 for my 3 digit number everything prints blank. For example:

Enter a 3 digit number: 123
Hundreds place digit: 
Tens place digit: 
Ones place digit: 
Error! Number more then 3 digits.
Error! Number less then 3 digits.

It's not detecting my input of '123' for example, or anything else I put.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
        public class ValueOfDigits {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                //Create new scanner
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                //Values of each digit
                int hundreds = 0;
                int tens = 0;
                int ones = 0;

                //Prompt user to input 3 digit number           
                System.out.print("Enter a 3 digit number: ");
                int number = input.nextInt();

                //Displays hundreds place digit
                hundreds = number / 100;
                System.out.printf("Hundreds place digit: " , hundreds);

                //Displays tens digit
                tens = (number - hundreds) / 10;
                System.out.printf("\nTens place digit: " , tens);


                //Display ones digit
                ones = (number - tens - hundreds);
                System.out.printf("\nOnes place digit: " , ones);   


                //Error if number is less or more then three digits
                if (number > 999); 
                System.out.println("\nError! Number more then 3 digits.");
                if (number < 100);
                System.out.println("Error! Number less then 3 digits.");
}
```

}

Comment: What doesn't work? Are there any errors, or is the output wrong? Please [edit] your question to include any more necessary information.

Comment: Suppose the user enters the number 256.  What is the value of `hundreds` in that case?  What would the result of `number - hundreds` be?

Comment: When I type in any 3 digit number everything comes up blank and throws my "if" errors. It's like its not detecting my input of numbers in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `System.out.printf("Hundreds place digit: " , hundreds);` with `System.out.println("Hundreds place digit: " + hundreds);` and remove the `;` after the `if`-statments.

If you want to use `printf` take a look at this:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was doing something wrong. My errors and hundreds place are working now, my tens and ones aren't displaying the right number though.

Answer (score 8):

We can get ones, hundred or any other place value in Java using a simple code as shown below:

```
int n=356;
int one=(n/1)%10;
int tens= (n/10)%10;
int hundred = (n/100)%10;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have little error of calculating tenth and ones digit.

```
           //Displays tens digit
            tens = (number %100) / 10;
            System.out.println("Tens place digit: " + tens);

            //Display ones digit
            ones = number %10;
            System.out.println("Ones place digit: " ,+ ones);
```

Remove semicolons after if conditions.

Again, the 3 digit checking should be done just after reading the number. Otherwise pointless calculation will be done for invalid numbers.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Completely Fixed code is here :
You can compare with your code to find error in your code

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
       class ValueOfDigits {
          public static void main(String[] args) 
           {
             //Create new scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Values of each digit
            int hundreds = 0;
            int tens = 0;
            int ones = 0;

            //Prompt user to input 3 digit number           
            System.out.print("Enter a 3 digit number: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

  if (number <= 999 && number > 99)   // Checking condition for three digit number
  {

            //Displays hundreds place digit
            hundreds = number / 100;
            System.out.printf("Hundreds place digit: " + hundreds);

            //Displays tens digit
            tens = (number - (hundreds*100)) / 10;  // compare with your code
            System.out.printf("\nTens place digit: " + tens);


            //Display ones digit
            ones = (number - (tens*10) - (hundreds*100));   // compare with your code
            System.out.printf("\nOnes place digit: " + ones);   
  }
                             //Error if number is less or more then three digits
else                                                                    
{      
  if (number > 999)
            System.out.println("\nError! Number more then 3 digits.");
            if (number < 100)
            System.out.println("Error! Number less then 3 digits.");
  }



  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int number=18970;

        int one=(number/1)
        int ones=(number/1)%10;
        int tens=(number/10)%10;
        int hundred=(number/100)%10;
        int thousand=(number/1000)%10;
        int tenThousand=(number/10000)%10;
        double result = (number/10)%10;

      System.out.println("Ones: " + ones + " Tens: "+ tens + " Hundred: "+ hundred + " Thousand: " + thousand +" Ten Thousand:  " +  tenThousand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to have an explaination of how modulus and integrer division work in this case

Answer (score -1):

```
class Source {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Create new scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Values of each digit
    int tenThousands=0;
    int thousands=0; 
    int hundreds=0; 
    int tens=0; 
    int ones=0;

    //Prompt user to input 5 digit number
       
    int n = input.nextInt();
    if (n > 99999) {
        System.out.println("\nError! Number more than 5 digits.");
        }
    else if (n < 10000) {
        System.out.println("Error! Number less than 5 digits.");
        }
    else if (10000<=n&&n<=99999){
      tenThousands = n/10000;
            System.out.println(tenThousands);
      thousands = (n/1000)%10;
      System.out.println(thousands);
      hundreds = (n%1000)/100;
            System.out.println(hundreds);
      tens = (n%100)/10;
            System.out.println(tens);
      ones = n%10;
            System.out.println(ones);
 


       
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain how this code works.

Answer (score -2):

```
'import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    if (a < 10) {
      System.out.println(0);
    } else {
      System.out.println((a- (a/100)*100)/10);
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Hi @Shakhobbek, please post an answer before you are sure that you've understood the question completely. The question wants to show three values of a three-digit number. You can test your code firstly using http://codepen.io/